# Android Studio not rendering preview

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I know this is common question, but I have tried

- Cleaning and Rebuilding Project
- Invalidating and restarting
- Setting build version to other that 22
- Changing version of Gradle
- adding `Base.` in `styles.xml` 
  and none of this doesn't fix the issue.

It's seems that this time the problem is somewhere else, because all elements are up-to-date.

I am getting following error at the preview screen in Android Studio :

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Gradle version is 1.2.3. I have just installed Android Studio + SDK.

Build gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sth.sth"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does your build.gradle look like?

Comment: @AlexFlorescu question edited

Comment: @kodw did you find any solution? I am stuck on the same issue for 3 days

Comment: @Siddhant Saurabh after sometime it managed to work. I think it was thanks to some updates from Android Studio, but I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Finally the error is gone. It appears to me that it was some sort of bug in Android Studio 1.2. Its gone when I updated to 1.3. For anyone who still faces the issue: Update!!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the toolbar from the support library, but it seems that you aren't including it as a dependency. You should add something like this in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I have this dependences I just haven't attached them to my question