# Why is my layout preview in Android Studio empty?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, sdk, android-ide

My issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691904/rendering-problems-for-android-studio) but Android Studio doesn't tell me anything about a rendering issue or compiler/build errors(I was able to build fine).

Here is what I am seeing(this is a new project)  [image]

And the contents of content_main.xml [image]

After reading on different rendering issue threads, I I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, invalidate caches/restart and even starting a new project to see if the layout preview was working(Still empty)

I also played around with different sdk versions(20,19) to see if the layout preview was working but all I got was this quirky [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653012/layout-preview-rendering-problems-porterduff-color-filters-are-not-supported) that I don't think would cause the layout preview to not work.

Does anyone know what my problem is here? I didn't mess around with my initial Gradle files and remove any support [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460438/android-studio-not-rendering-preview) dependencies. Another solution I had in mind was reinstalling Android Studio but that's last resort.

Comment: i had the same problem, it worked for me when i update Android Studio

Comment: is that happening only in content_main.xml or very xml file ?

Comment: Never mind. Did more updates. did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

Just check your sdk valid version like example.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your TextView element into an empty FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_groups" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This code above should be put inside your RelativeLayout. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry then. I had a similar problem, when elements of UI were not shown, and this helped me to solve, so I thought it could be the same.